# PHP read database Table length

Tags: php, database

I have problem with reading Length of table,

i want make it like this :-

```
if length < 10

    echo "length is less than 10"

else

    echo "length is more than 10"
```

this is my code

```
$sql1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
if(mysql_fetch_lengths($sql1) < 10) {
    echo ("length less than 10");
    exit();
} else {
    echo ("length more than 10");
    exit();
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: You should use `count(*)` in the query to get the number of rows.  And, you should update to "mysqli".

Comment: Pretty sure you want to loop over the result of mysql_fetch_lengths($sql1) because it returns the length of each field in an array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-lengths.php

Comment: What Gordon said. In this particular case `mysql_fetch_lengths` returns an array, not an integer, the thing you want is in array values.

Comment: What exactly is the length you are trying check is less than 10? 
Are you trying to check the number of records, or the length of a specific field, or even the length of each field?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
<?php           
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `account` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
    $sql1= mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if( ! $sql1 ) {
        //query ok      
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql1 );                     
        if( $row['num'] < 10 ) {
            $msg = "length less than 10";
        }else {
            $msg = "length more than 10";
        }
        echo $msg;              
    }       
    exit();            
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you want use mysql_num_rows()

```
$sql1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql1) < 10) {
    echo ("length less than 10");
    exit();
} else {
    echo ("length more than 10");
    exit();
}
```